# How to write unit test for function that calls React.UseEffect in it ( code included )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Scroll.js

```
import React from "react";

export const ScrollToTop = ({ children, location }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), [location.pathname]);
  return children;
};
```

Scroll.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { ScrollToTop } from "./ScrollToTop";

describe("ScrollToTop", () => {
  it("", () => {
    expect(
      ScrollToTop({
        children: "some children",
        location: { pathname: "the path" }
      })
    ).toEqual();
  });
});
```

and the result I'm getting is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dy5T.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `ScrollToTop` as a function directly, this is what error message is complaining about.

[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing.html) recommend the [Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) for writing tests.

Here is an example of how you can write `Scroll.test.js` using the library above:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ScrollToTop } from "./ScrollToTop";

describe("ScrollToTop", () => {
  it('calls window.scrollTo()', () => {
    window.scrollTo = jest.fn(); // create a moack function and record all calls
    render(<ScrollToTop location={{ pathname: 'pathname' }}>Text</ScrollToTop>); // render a component

    expect(window.scrollTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0, 0); // check that scrollTo mock was called
  });
});
```